# How to check that the address pointed by a pointer is pointing to an object not a garbage before reading or writing to this object?

Tags: c++, c++11

If i have a pointer (static address) that will always point to a specific variable address (ex.health) then how to check if the game.exe destroyed and deallocates this object before program reads and writes to this non existing object at this time?

```
static DWORD baseAddress = 0x00000 ;
static DWORD healthPtr = (DWORD)(baseAddress + health_offset);

//when the game deallocates and destroys health object it's value become (??) garbage causing crash on reading or writing to it!

//So how to check here if the address pointing to health is realy pointing to a valid health object not a destroyed non sense garbage?

*(int*)(healthPtr) = 100;
// writing to a deallocated object will cause a crash
```

Comment: Use `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` if it's possible for the pointer to be invalidated.  There's no way to check this with just raw pointers.

Comment: Pointers are blissfully ignorant of anything other than the address they hold and there is no back channel from object to pointer (think of the book-keeping that would require) so there is no way to inform a pointer that the object it references is no more.

Comment: The nullptr check before reading or writing to health var  realy worked for my situation!!        if((int*)healthptr != nullptr) so if true then the health var is holding int value so i can read and write it and if false so var contains garbage so i can stop reading and writing it